# Is there a simple enough formula for this geometric series problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

A friend of mine has recently started a challenge in which he starts by doing 22 pressups and then nominates somebody else to do 22 pressups the next day. This continues every day in which those who have not exceeded 22 nominations (22 days) continue to do their pressups and make their nominations.

What is the geometric formula for this progression? This assumes no one asks the same person twice and everyone accepts their nomination. Additionally how long before the number of people involved will exceed the population of the Earth at ~7.4 billion?

This begins as a simple 2^n progression however after the 22nd day it gets complicated as my friend is no longer involved, and those that have exceeded their 22 day period no longer participate.

Ideally I would like to say how many people will be doing pressups on day 50/60/70 etc, is it possible to derive a formula that I can plug these number into to work this out? It would be easy to create a program to compute this but I wondered if it could be worked out by simple pen and paper and perhaps a calculator alone.

Comment: It's no so simple as $2^n$ to start with.  Have you worked out the first few days?

Comment: n = 0; p1 doing pressups, nominates p2. n = 1; p1 doing pressups nominates p3 and p2 doing pressups nominate p4; n = 2; p1, p2, p3 and p4 doing pressups and they nominate p5, p6, p7 and p8. That is 1, 2, 4 or 2^0, 2^1 and 2^2. I don't see how this wouldn't continue until the 23rd day??

Comment: So if someone gets nominated on (for example) the first of the month: starting on the 2nd on the month, they do 22 pressups and give 1 nomination per day, every day, for 22 days? So on the 23rd day of the month, that's the last time they participate, and then on the 24th of the month, they stop?

Comment: Yes @MarcusStuhr the first person who on day 1 is the only person doing pressups will not be doing pressups on day 23. On day 23 they stop being involved but the rest continue until they reach their 23rd day. So on the 23rd day the number of people involved is 2^22 - 1 (they still nominate), after this it gets hazy for me as on 24th days it will be 2 ^ 22 - 3 I think as there is another dropout from day 2 and the missed nomination from the first person dropping out...

Comment: @MattTallyn before an edit was made, the phrasing suggested each person nominates 22 new people each day.  That would be much larger than $2^n$, but it seems clear now that each person nominates $1$ new person each day for 22 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be modeled with a linear recurrence.

The first person to begin starts on Day $1$, which means we can treat him as if he were nominated on Day $0$, since anyone who is nominated begins the challenge starting the following day.

Let $T(n)$ be the number of people participating on day $n$ (i.e. the number of people who are doing pressups / giving out nominations on that day):

$$T(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{22} T(n-k)$$

Base cases: $T(n)=0$ for $n<0$, $T(0) = 1$, and $T(n) = 2^{n-1}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 22$.

This is similar to the Fibonacci sequence, except instead of degree $2$, it's degree $22$.

Day $34$ is when the total number of participants exceeds the planet's population, at $T(34) = 8589921280$.

Here is a table of results:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
n &T(n)\\
\hline
1 & 1 \\
\hline
2 & 2 \\
\hline
3 & 4 \\
\hline
4 & 8 \\
\hline
5 & 16 \\
\hline
6 & 32 \\
\hline
7 & 64 \\
\hline
8 & 128 \\
\hline
9 & 256 \\
\hline
10 & 512 \\
\hline
11 & 1024 \\
\hline
12 & 2048 \\
\hline
13 & 4096 \\
\hline
14 & 8192 \\
\hline
15 & 16384 \\
\hline
16 & 32768 \\
\hline
17 & 65536 \\
\hline
18 & 131072 \\
\hline
19 & 262144 \\
\hline
20 & 524288 \\
\hline
21 & 1048576 \\
\hline
22 & 2097152 \\
\hline
23 & 4194303 \\
\hline
24 & 8388605 \\
\hline
25 & 16777208 \\
\hline
26 & 33554412 \\
\hline
27 & 67108816 \\
\hline
28 & 134217616 \\
\hline
29 & 268435200 \\
\hline
30 & 536870336 \\
\hline
31 & 1073740544 \\
\hline
32 & 2147480832 \\
\hline
33 & 4294961152 \\
\hline
34 & 8589921280 \\
\hline
35 & 17179840512 \\
\hline
36 & 34359676928 \\
\hline
37 & 68719345664 \\
\hline
38 & 137438674944 \\
\hline
39 & 274877317120 \\
\hline
40 & 549754568704 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Python 2.x script:

```
DEGREE = 22 

cache = {}

def T(n):
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if n==0:
        return 1
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    cache[n] = sum(T(n-k) for k in xrange(1, DEGREE+1))
    return cache[n]

for n in xrange(1, 41):
    print "n = %s, T(n) = %s" % (n, T(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is through generating functions.

Let $a_n$ be the number of people participating on day $n$, starting with 1 person on day one ($a_0=1$) who participates on days 0,...,21, and who invites 22 new participants who start on days 1,...,22.

We represent this sequence $a_n$ through a generating function: $A(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n x^n.$ This is just a formal power series, so we don't even require that it converge, although it will in our case.

Now, the first person participates on days 0,...,21, which contribute the sum $1+x+\cdots+x^21$ to $A(x)$. The person invited to start on day $k=1,\ldots,22$ will start a new chain of invitation, leading to $a_n$ participants on day $k+n$, which contributes $x^kA(x)$ for each $k$. So this makes the total
$$
A(x)=(1+x+\cdots x^{21})+(x+\cdots+x^{22})A(x)
=\frac{1-x^{22}}{1-x}\cdot(1+xA(x))
$$
which solves to
$$
A(x)=\frac{1-x^{22}}{1-2x+x^{23}}.
$$
If we rewrite this as $A(x)\cdot(1-2x+x^{23})=1-x^{22}$, we get $a_n=2^n$ for $n=0,\ldots,21$, $a_{22}=2^{22}-1$ as the first participant leaves, and thereafter we get $a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-23}$.

In the long run, I would expect $a_n\sim C\cdot 1.999999762^n$ based on the roots of $1-2x+x^{23}$ (haven't checked this properly).